# Virtual audio driver for windows 10 server

Tags: audio, drivers, microphone

I own an AWS server and I launched a virtual machine and ran on it some servers I programmed. I am also using teamspeak in that VM so I want to make a bot there that can play sounds, but my problem is that the server computer doesn't have a microphone or microphone driver at all. I just need a virtual audio driver to pretend that my server has a microphone although it doesn't. 
I already tried VAC and it didn't work.

Comment: Here's a VAC alternative: http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm.   Although I'm curious to know what issue you ran into with VAC, as this is a prime use case for it I would think.

Comment: @BenJacobson I installed it but I just don't see the the virtual device in my recording devices..

Comment: @BenJacobson check the log from VAC: http://prntscr.com/e1ncj1